# Badzipfile error with openpyxl in anaconda environment

Tags: python, automation, openpyxl

hello Am new in python and Am trying to learn it, i made a small code to automate a task on excel using the openpyxl package and am working with a small spreadsheet 'transactions.xlsx' but i a got an error when i try to read the sheet. please help me to fix that

this is my code following:

```
  import openpyxl as xl
    wb= xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
    sheet = wb ['Sheet1']
    cell = sheet['a1']
    print(cell.value)`
```

and the message i got :

```
PS C:\Users\ryan\helloworld> & C:/Users/ryan/anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/ryan/helloworld/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ryan\helloworld\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    wb= xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init_rkbook_
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)                                                         _
  File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive                                                                                        e_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1267, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1334, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: The code block shown above contains indentation errors that will prevent it from running, and a trailing backtick that should not be there. Please [edit] your question and revise your code into a functional [code block]. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are typos and which are legitimate.

Comment: Either way the error suggests your file 'transactions.xlsx' is corrupt. Can you open it in Excel? or even in a zip app like winzip or 7zip? Your code looks fine notwithstanding indent and misc characters, so does it work with another xlsx file. (ensure the files are xlsx and not xls).

Answer (score -2):

Try opening the file in binary mode and then passing that to the `load_workbook`. At least in the documentations it wants a file-like object to be opened in binary mode.

```
import openpyxl as xl
    myFile=open("path/to/transactions.xlsx", "rb")
    wb= xl.load_workbook(myFile)
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    cell = sheet['a1']
    print(cell.value)
```